# Sum file sizes that contain K, M, G, T

Tags: shell, sum, zsh, filesize

If (in zsh) I have an array that contains something like this:

```
echo ${fsizes[@]}
9.5M 100M 5G 15G 1.2T
```

is there an easy way to get the sum of these in an output of choice (i.e. bytes, megabytes, gigabytes etc?)

Comment: I suppose, the easiest way to calculate the sum is to use sizes with one unit. Byte for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/zsh

fsizes=( 9.5M 100M 5G 15G 1.2T )

typeset -A unit
unit=( B 1 K 1024 M 1048576 G 1073741824 T 1099511627776 )

sumSize(){
    sum=0
    for sz; do
        u=${sz//[^BKMGT]/}
        n=${sz//$u/}
        b=${unit[$u]}
        (( sum += b * n ))
    done
    out="${@:(-1)}"
    echo "Sum is $(( sum / ${unit[$out]} )) $out"
}
```

#### Example with output in Bytes

```
$ sumSize ${fsizes[@]} "B"
Sum is 1341003608883.2 B
```

#### Example with output in Kilobytes

```
$ sumSize ${fsizes[@]} "K"
Sum is 1309573836.8 K
```

#### Example with output in Megabytes

```
$ sumSize ${fsizes[@]} "M"
Sum is 1278880.7 M
```

#### Example with output in Gigabytes

```
$ sumSize ${fsizes[@]} "G"
Sum is 1248.90693359375 G
```

#### Example with output in Terabytes

```
$ sumSize ${fsizes[@]} "T"
Sum is 1.2196356773376464 T
```

Comment: It might take me some time to figure this out but I know this is a +1 material! :)